# Problem with assembly (emu8086): It doesn't print the right value

Tags: assembly, ascii, x86-16, emu8086

When I compile and execute the code with emu8086, it doesn't print the right value. Rather it prints the value 0. I don't understand why. Can someone please explain this to me?

This is the code:

```
    format MZ   

entry code_seg:start ; set entry point

stack 256  

segment data_seg

     
     VAR1 DB 5     

    
segment code_seg
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data_seg
    mov ds, ax


    
    ;print the value
    MOV AH,02H
    MOV DL,VAR1       
    ADD DL,30H
    INT 21H
    
    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    
    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h
```

Comment: Try to temporarily replace `MOV DL,VAR1` with `MOV DL,5`. If it prints the character **5**,  seek the error in data addressing.

Comment: Yes, i've just tried and with the value 5 it prints correctly. But when i use a variable it doesn't work and i don't understand why.

Comment: Look how was `MOV DL,VAR1` encoded, it should be `8A160000`.  If it's `B200`, change `MOV DL,VAR1` into `MOV DL,[VAR1]`. Brackets `[]` generally signalize that you want to load `DL` from the **memory** and not with the lower half of the offset of `VAR`, and stupid emu didn't understand your intention.

Comment: Are you using fasm? The directives in the source look like fasm.

Comment: No, only Emu8086... however the problem was solver with brackets in VAR1 [ ]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in Data segment you need to append h after value
so your data segment should be like these.

```
VAR1 DB 05h
```

Comment: `5` (decimal), `5h` (hex), and `05h` are the same numeric value, and will assemble to the same 8-bit binary byte in memory.